# raydium-amm rust

Tags: solana-program, rust

Is it possible to obtain `minimum_amount_out` using the [Raydium AMM library](https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-amm/) when I try to retrieve and insert it into the transaction using the following code:

```
let swap_amount_out = Calculator::swap_token_amount_base_in(
    swap_in_after_deduct_fee,
    total_pc_without_take_pnl.into(),
    total_coin_without_take_pnl.into(),
    swap_direction,
).as_u64();
swap_base_in.minimum_amount_out = swap_amount_out;
```

However, when attempting to send the transaction, I receive the error: `"instruction exceeds desired slippage limit."` It is likely that I am doing something wrong, but I do not understand what is correct in this case. Could you please provide guidance on what I might be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.